# Align Webview at the bottom end of Adview

Tags: android, webview, admob, android-webview, adview

I have an `AdView` and a `WebView` in my Constraintlayout. The ads appearing on testing are 90dp height but in real situations might be 50dp or 30dp depending on the resolution screen. I use  `android:layout_marginTop="90dp"` for my `WebView` to align it under the `AdView`.

Is there a way to change the marginTop value programmatically and align the  `WebView` vertically under the `AdView`based on the height of the ad it shows?

Here is my activity.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView1"
    
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/adview_border"
        app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="1232131231"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    >
</WebView>
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf` on the `WebView` and align it according to the AdMob. Below is a sample code you can try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/adview_border"
            app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            app:adUnitId="1232131231"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/adView1" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```